# Creating a JSON schema for Acumatica invoice creation with REST API

Tags: c#, json, json.net, acumatica

I am trying to create a JSON schema using the Json.NET that matches the definition that Acumatica uses. When I serialize the object, it parses like {"KEY":"VALUE"}, but Acumatica requires it to be formatted as {"KEY": {Value Keyword: "VALUE" }.

Anyone out there create a schema using Json.NET to accomplish this?

Comment: How is `Value Keyword` determined?

Comment: I'd highly recommend you not go down this hole, you wont be able to escape. Use either the .NET api, OpenAPI (swagger)  or good old fashioned WSDL. This is a battle you wont win.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay If I look at the swagger file, the definition for creating invoices includes: ' "Customer": {"value": "string"} ' in the schema body. If I serialize the object using the Json.NET library, it parses it as ' "Customer":"C008352" '. I should be able to create a schema definition that can be used, no? Or am I just required to loop through members of the class and manually create a valid serialized string to pass to the Put method of the API?

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, you can't build a *schema* that will transfer your POCO into Acumatica-accepted JSON. You either have to adapt your POCO to Acumatica expectations (i.e., use value wrappers in each property, as the SOAP-generated classes do), or write a custom `JsonConverter` to write your POCO the way Acumatica wants it.

Comment: Thanks @Srogovtsev. As I'm new to Acumatica and StackOverflow, my question could probably have been phrased better/differently. In fact, I was looking to write a custom JsonConverter and looking for help/resources with that. I've manually built the JSON string and am validating it against the entity specification. If there is a resource out there to help me clean up the code and make use of JsonConverter, I'm happy to see it.